# Eclipse Android Project Java Buid Issue

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Just installed Eclipse Luna on a new computer with Ubuntu 14.10.

Copied my workspace over.

My projects will not build. The Console continues to show "Java Problem."

For example one of the 500ish errors with Java Problem:

```
Animator cannot be resolved to a type   DefaultClusterRenderer.java /library/src/com/google/maps/android/clustering/view    line 882    Java Problem
```

And it says the same "Java Problem" for about 500 more lines.

I have:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
```

as my java path and I also have a copy of the JRE folder with contents within the eclipse folder.

What am I leaving out? My projects were building fine on my old computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When importing a workspace into a new computer or version of Eclipse, make sure that your target build versions are the same as in your previous workspace. This project required the Google Play Services Library and a Google Maps Library. Both of which had been marked with a target build of a deprecated version of Android.

Right clicking properties on your project and then selecting Android will allow you to change the build target as needed.